# Unable to see the Executable JAR File in the apache JMeter bin folder

Tags: java, jmeter, windows-10

Following this YouTube [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A55CV8EwKw4&t=7s),

- I have downloaded the Apache JMeter 5.6.2, extracted in the downloads folder.
- Placed that extracted folder in the C drive - Program Files directory.
- Opened to bin folder > I cannot see the executable Jar File as shown in the video to open the J Meter.
  [image: Youtube Video Screenshot]

But I can see the Jar file named as Apache J Meter, it is not showing the Java SE environment option to open the application:

[image]

The ApacheJMeter file icon also showing as winrar symbol for me but in the video it is shown as Java application logo.

How to resolve this issue and install the ApacheJMeter perfectly in Windows System?

Comment: Read jmeter documentation instead of random YouTube tutorials. Also what your Windows installation shows as icons is not related to jmeter but to whatever you installed on Windows. You seem to not understand your Windows installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like an issue with your [Windows file associations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/fa-intro). The `ApacheJMeter.jar` file is there but your operating system considers it as an archive and it makes sense because [.jar files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/basicsindex.html) are basically [.zip archives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_(file_format)).

Anyway you're not supposed to launch `ApacheJMeter.jar` file directly, you should use `jmeter.bat` wrapper script because it does some checks and sets some parameters which are necessary to properly initialize and run JMeter.

[image]

In general I would recommend following [official JMeter documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#install) which states:

> To run JMeter, run the jmeter.bat (for Windows) or jmeter (for Unix) file. These files are found in the bin directory.

If you need a little more detailed instructions check out [JMeter Installation: How to Get Started](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-installation) article